# Question on Proof strategy For exercise

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Problem: Prove If $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and if $c|a$ and $d|b$, then $\gcd(c,d) =1$

Question: My strategy is to use contradiction and set $\gcd(c,d)= k, k\neq 1$ Then if $\gcd(c,d) = k$ then $k|c$ and $k|d$ so by transitive property $k|a$ and $k|b$ implying $k|1$ which is a contradiction. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: looks correct to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $\ \begin{eqnarray} k\mid c\mid a\\ k\mid d\mid b\end{eqnarray}\,\Rightarrow\, k\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, k\mid (a,b)= 1.\,$ It shows $\,(c,d)\mid (a,b)\,$ more generally.

Comment: aaah ok. thanks.